# Collapsing the lower of 2 navbars with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to implement a double-navbar system in Bootstrap.  The affect I want is for the top navbar to be uncollapsable and unchangeable as the screen size decreases (this won't be a problem visually because I only have a logo and sign in/up button on the top navbar so there's no need to hide anything).  Then I want a second navbar immediately underneath that which will contain lots more options and DOES need to collapse on smaller screens - but when it collapses I want the hamburger icon to appear on the same navbar level  (i.e. the lower navbar, not the top one).  Here's what I've got so far...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">

   <!--this div shows my existing hacky solution to fix a button in the middle of the top navbar without it collapsing (i.e. I just define it outside of the navbar!)-->
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
        <div style="position: relative; left: -50%;"> 
            <button class="button"><span style="float: left;"id="selectedButtonSpan">Button Text</span></button>
        </div>
  </div>

<!--this covers BOTH NAVBARS - not sure if that's the correct way to do it-->
  <div class="container-fluid no-padding">

        <!--this is the hamburger that appears when the page collapses past a certain point but it appears on the top nav whereas I want it to appear on the bottom nav-->
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style = "line-height: 30px;">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!--top navbar - nothing should change here (i.e. I don't want it to ever collapse) but when I change the class from navbar-collapse to navbar-default, it won't even appear when the page loads-->
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

             <div class="navbar-brand" id="logo"></div> 
             <div id="userAccountButton" class="userAccountButton"> 

        </div>

        <!--second navbar - this should collapse (which it does successfully) but the hamburger icon should appear on the same level -->
        <div id="navbar2" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="background-color: #66CCFF;">  <!-- collapse navbar-collapse to collapse to nothing when page shrinks-->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>Option A</li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li>Option B</li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li>Option C</li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li>Option D</li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li>Option E</li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

    </div><!-- container-fluid no-padding -->
</nav><!-- navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse -->
```

What happens is that everything looks great on a full size screen, but then when I shrink the page past the collapse point, the second/bottom navbar collapses (correctly), but there's 2 problems with the top navbar...

1. the divs it contains disappear (i.e. the logo and account button)
2. the hamburger icon appears on this level (whereas it should appear on the second/bottom navbar)

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental here, but would really appreciate any thoughts on why the structure I'm using isn't working - I know I need to change the class of the top-navbar, but that alone just causes it to disappear so I'm hoping someone can suggest a better way to group the navbars.  Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I believe this is what you're trying to build. It can be as simple as placing one `navbar` over another and making a few adjustments for positioning.

See working Example Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  border-top: none;
}
.navbar-inverse.nav-top ul {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-top > li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-top > li > a {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar-inverse navbar-static-top nav-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand-top" href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50/fff/222?text=LOGO">
    </a>

    <ul class="nav navbar-top">
      <li><a href="#">sign up</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">login</a>

      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-lower" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-lower">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Foo</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Bar</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Foo</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Bar</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Foo</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Bar</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.